# How can I retrieve a Windows Credential from Windows Credential Manager in python?

Tags: python, windows

I tried using the keyring package to do it, but from what I have found, it actually looks only in the "Generic Credentials" section, but I need to retrieve credentials specifically defined in the Windows Credentials section.

[image]